# Getting error while parsing json response from a dynamic {System.RuntimeType} variable

Tags: json, linq, dynamic

I'm working on some code in which uses dynamic variables **jsonResponse** .

```
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
```

This variable contains collection of hotel list in json format. From this collection I am getting roomlist collection in a new variable **roomResponseList** :

```
var roomResponseList = jsonResponse["hotels"]["hotels"][rooms].roomResponseList;
```

I am getting first room detail into **JObject responseRateKeys **:

```
foreach (var roomByResponse in roomResponseList)
{
    JObject responseRateKeys = JObject.Parse(roomByResponse.ToString());
    var boardNameListByResponse = responseRateKeys.AsJEnumerable().AsEnumerable()
                                                   .Select(t => t["rates"]["boardName"].ToString().Trim())
                                                   .Distinct()
                                                   .ToList();
}
```

But when I am trying to get any item list from JObject by using linq lambda, I am getting error,
"**Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.**"

Value of roomByResponse=

```
{ "code": "DBL.KG-NM", "name": "DOUBLE KING BED NON SMOKING", "rates": [ { "rateKey": "20171217|20171219|W|256|237403|DBL.KG-NM|ID_B2B_26|RO|IWH25|1~1~0||N@AFF5C93E36054661ADCBC14A78A532AE1007", "rateClass": "NRF", "rateType": "RECHECK", "net": "186.04", "allotment": 99, "paymentType": "AT_WEB", "packaging": false, "boardCode": "RO", "boardName": "ROOM ONLY", "cancellationPolicies": [ { "amount": "149.63", "from": "2017-07-14T03:29:00+05:30" } ], "rooms": 1, "adults": 1, "children": 0, "dailyRates": [ { "offset": 1, "dailyNet": "93.02" }, { "offset": 2, "dailyNet": "93.02" } ] }, { "rateKey": "20171217|20171219|W|256|237403|DBL.KG-NM|ID_B2B_26|BB|IWB25|1~1~0||N@AFF5C93E36054661ADCBC14A78A532AE1007", "rateClass": "NOR", "rateType": "RECHECK", "net": "238.92", "allotment": 99, "paymentType": "AT_WEB", "packaging": false, "boardCode": "BB", "boardName": "BED AND BREAKFAST", "rooms": 1, "adults": 1, "children": 0, "dailyRates": [ { "offset": 1, "dailyNet": "119.46" }, { "offset": 2, "dailyNet": "119.46" } ] }, { "rateKey": "20171217|20171219|W|256|237403|DBL.KG-NM|ID_B2B_26|RO|IWH25|2~2~1|2|N@AFF5C93E36054661ADCBC14A78A532AE1007", "rateClass": "NRF", "rateType": "RECHECK", "net": "372.06", "allotment": 99, "paymentType": "AT_WEB", "packaging": false, "boardCode": "RO", "boardName": "ROOM ONLY", "cancellationPolicies": [ { "amount": "299.25", "from": "2017-07-14T03:29:00+05:30" } ], "rooms": 2, "adults": 2, "children": 1, "childrenAges": "2", "dailyRates": [ { "offset": 1, "dailyNet": "186.03" }, { "offset": 2, "dailyNet": "186.03" } ] }, { "rateKey": "20171217|20171219|W|256|237403|DBL.KG-NM|ID_B2B_26|BB|IWB25|2~2~1|2|N@AFF5C93E36054661ADCBC14A78A532AE1007", "rateClass": "NOR", "rateType": "RECHECK", "net": "477.84", "allotment": 99, "paymentType": "AT_WEB", "packaging": false, "boardCode": "BB", "boardName": "BED AND BREAKFAST", "rooms": 2, "adults": 2, "children": 1, "childrenAges": "2", "dailyRates": [ { "offset": 1, "dailyNet": "238.92" }, { "offset": 2, "dailyNet": "238.92" } ] } ] }
```

Thank you
Pravesh Singh

Answer (score 0):

change linq to

```
responseRateKeys["rates"].AsJEnumerable().Select(t=>t["boardName"]).Distinct().ToList()
```